# create json string list from gorm query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain object

```
class ProductQuantity implements Comparable {

    static constraints = {
    }

    Integer quantity

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }

    static belongsTo = Product
    static hasMany = [products:Product]

    int compareTo(obj) {
        quantity.compareTo(obj.quantity)
    }

}
```

I'd like to return a JSON string that looks like this [50,100,200]

With gorm, is there away to easily do this without having to loop the object and create a set?

I started here

```
def availableQuantities = ProductQuantity.findAll()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this from a controller :

```
ProductQuantity.list() as JSON
```

You can control the json in several ways :

1/ Register a JSON marshaller in Bootstrap.groovy :

```
class Bootstrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(ProductQuantity) {
            return it.quantity
        }
    }
}
```

2/ For your simple case, you could also add a toString method to your ProductQuantity class that returns the quantity property

3/ For more complex use cases, you can create custom named configurations (if you want to produce different types of JSON from the same domain class). [See this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/07/grails-goodness-using-converter-named.html).